# Python get Index of max Value in a List: Error Value is in List but doesn't find it

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the index of the max value in a list. It did work so far but now I needed to make it in a loop and save those indexes and values in a list. Somehow I get an error saying that my max value is not in the list, although I can clearly see that is in there.

What my code does so far:
I am iterating through a JSON file. In there I have a list of many values `y00B`. in this list, I saved some indices in a code before `res = file['labelindices']`.
now in the range between each of those indices, I want to get the max value and its index

here my code:

```
        for file in json_data[sizes[i]]:
            count += 1                        # counting the files i am iterating trough
            res = file['labelindices']        # indices i want to get the values from
            y00B = file['triggerdata']        # list of my data
            for r in range(0, 2):
                valuesPeak = y00B[res[r]:res[r+2]] # this is right, do not ask :)
                print('valuesPeak:',valuesPeak)
                print('max value of current list', max(valuesPeak), 'count file = '
                      , count, ', length', len(valuesPeak))
                if len(valuesPeak) == 0:
                    valuesPeak = 0
                if valuesPeak == 0:
                    max_val.append(0)
                    max_index.append(0)
                else:
                    max_val.append(max(valuesPeak))
                    print(y00B.index(max_val))
                    max_index.append(y00B.index(max_val))
```

and this is the error message and my printouts:

```
>> ValueError: [44431] is not in list
valuesPeak:  [26793, 29441, 32237, 35061, 37752, 40162, 42121, 43505, 44278, 44431, 43984, 42923, 41367, 39408, 37258, 34943, 32617, 30330]
max value of current list 44431 count file =  1 , length 18
```

can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? The value is clearly in the list. why can't it be found?
when I rewrite the code without my `for r range (0,2)` loop it works perfectly fine, but I need to write it 2 times which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, `max_val` is a list itself, and a list does not appear in your *list of numbers*.

Comment: I am a total beginner in python so this was only partly helpful. After trying many things i got my answer. I posted it below. would have appreciated a bit more support to be honest. I can understand that code like this seems super simple to few people, but try to remember, everybody is starting somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the max_val variable bc it seems I only need the index. the code is:

```
    max_index = []
    for i in range(0, sizesCount):
        for file in json_data[sizes[i]]:
            res = file['labelindices']
            y00B = file['triggerdata']
            for r in range(0, 2):
                valuesPeak = y00B[res[r]:res[r+2]] #0 ans 2, 1 and 3
                if len(valuesPeak) == 0:
                    valuesPeak = 0
                    max_index.append(0)
                else:
                    max_index.append(y00B.index(max(valuesPeak)))
            particlesize[sizes[i]].append({
            'maxvalpeak685index': max_index[0],
            'maxvalpeak450index': max_index[1]
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can find index of any value in your list:

```
Mylist = [8.,9,1.2,6.,25,12,3,7.5]
Mylist.index( max(Mylist) )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).